# Calculation of Group Cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am trying to learn some group cohomology and I'm starting to get my head around the theory, but I find it hard to find some explicit examples of the calculation of group cohomology of some small finite groups. For example, I think it would help my understanding to see a calculation of the Tate cohomology groups of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

On wikipedia it says that $$\hat{H}^p(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z};\mathbb{Z})=\begin{cases} 0, &p\text{ odd;}\\ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, &p\text{ even}.\end{cases}$$

Could someone show me how to compute this by explicit calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but the converse is not true. Hence $H^0(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z};\mathbb{Z})=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{Z}=0$. Right?

Comment: Any group can be given the trivial action.

Comment: @Hebe If $\mathbb{Z}$ weren't a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ module, $H^*(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{Z})$ wouldn't even be defined. (And $\mathbb{Z}$ even has *two* $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ actions, the trivial action, and the sign action).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, yes! Hence the cohomology depends on the action, right?

Comment: @Hebe Yes, but if nothing special is written it's generally assumed to be the trivial action (and the cohomology groups listed in the question are indeed those with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial action).

Comment: Yes, indeed I am asking about the cohomology groups under the trivial action here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action of any group G (here G = **Z**/2**Z**) on **Z** is always implicitly supposed to be the trivial action. If G is cyclic, there is a theorem saying that Tate cohomology is periodic, with period 2, more precisely H^p(G,M) is isomorphic to $H^{p+2}(G,M)$, so it suffices to compute H^0 and H^1, which are given explicitly by $H^0(G,M)=M^G/N(M)$ and $H^1(G,M)=KerN/(s-1)M$. Here s denotes a generator of G and N, the norm (or trace) map, is defined by $N(m)=$sum of all $s^i(m).$ This gives your answer.